# SQL Server LocalDB login/user cannot access .MDF file (when created with a different windows account)

Tags: sql-server, authentication, localdb, mdf

Our application has been live for several years. It's an installed WPF desktop application used by our customers. So, there's only so much we can control about the administration of the computers it runs on.

The application has an underlying SQL Server LocalDB .MDF database that it uses. The application has just been using basic Windows Authentication to access this database. However, we've been running into issues where the application will crash because it randomly looses permission to access the database during runtime. Also occasionally, a customer's IT will [incorrectly] merge domains and hose Windows user account access to the .MDF files.

To address this, I'm trying to add an explicit database user that the application will connect with. The idea is that this would be Windows user account independent and would add a layer of protection against customer IT departments doing unexpected things.

Anyway, I implemented this and it all works fine. It's in Internal Testing now. However, a couple of our project engineers running the new Test version have sent me their .MDF databases for me to investigate unrelated issues, and our application crashes immediately when I run it with their database:

```
Cannot open database "C:\MURRAY\CONTROLPRO\DATA\DATABASE.MDF" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'murray'.
```

Using Visual Studio to connect to the .MDF directly, I get this error:

[image: Visual Studio Connect]

[image: Login with 'murray' error message]

If I connect to the default 'master' database using the 'murray' user, I can connect just fine; and I can query the 'master' database normally. So, the 'murrray' user allows me to access the database instance. But when then I try to access the .MDF database, I see this:

[image: Switch databases while logged in as 'murray' error message]

Now this is where it gets strange... If I log out and log back in using Windows Authentication, I can access the .MDF just fine. I can query the server and database principals and see the 'murray' user there.

[image: 'murray' user present]

In order to get our application to access the .MDF again, I have to kill the 'SQL Server Windows NT - 64 Bit' task in the Task Manager, drop the 'murray' user and recreate it using the original SQL. After that, everything works again.

```
DROP USER murray;
DROP LOGIN murray;

CREATE LOGIN murray WITH PASSWORD = '12345'; -- It's what idiots have on their luggage...
CREATE USER murray FOR LOGIN murray;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'murray';
```

But this moots the entire point of having an explicit database user in the first place. If customer IT hoses the user's Windows user account, we're back to square one. And it makes customer support considerably harder.

Any thoughts on why an explicit database user will only work when using it with the same Windows user account that created it? Thanks!

Comment: That's not strange at all: you have added the `db_owner` role against the `master` database, not your database. You need to either do it under that database with `USE yourdb;` or you can do `EXEC yourdb.sys.sp_addrolemember ...`. Have you considered a shared instance of Localdb which means you can still use Windows Auth? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915521/how-to-share-sql-localdb-with-other-users-on-same-machine/22506141

Comment: I hadn't really thought about a shared LocalDB, as only one user account will ever be accessing the database at a time. This might come in useful in scenarios where the customer's IT screwed up their Windows Account during a domain merge. The last time that happened, I would kill SQL Server in the Task Manager, restart it manually from the command prompt, and still wouldn't be able to access the default instance with Windows Authentication. So, something was seriously wrong under the covers. I'm not a Windows Admin, so I can't even begin to guess what they did wrong.

Comment: But your first train of thought has merit. I thought I was applying the database user to the .MDF. So, I tried running a few different versions of the SQL and settled on this:

CREATE LOGIN murray WITH PASSWORD = '12345';
CREATE USER murray FOR LOGIN murray;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'murray';
USE [C:\MURRAY\CONTROLPRO\DATA\DATABASE.MDF];
CREATE USER murray FOR LOGIN murray;
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'murray';

Evidently, the LOGIN is instance-level. The USER and the SP EXEC are database specific. Unfortunately, there was no change in behavior.

Comment: Correct, logins are per instance, but users are per database. A database user is attached to a login

Answer (score 1):

That's a automatic user-specific instance of LocalDb.  The current Windows user owns the LocalDb instance, should always connect using Windows Auth, and needs Windows NTFS access to the .MDF file.

> **Connect to the automatic instance**
> The easiest way to use LocalDB is to
> connect to the automatic instance owned by the current user by using
> the connection string Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated
> Security=true. To connect to a specific database by using the file
> name, connect using a connection string similar to
> Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated
> Security=true;AttachDbFileName=D:\Data\MyDB1.mdf.

[LocalDb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15#connect-to-the-automatic-instance)

If you want SQL Server to "own" the database and grant users access to it, use a ["shared" LocalDb instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-ver15#connect-to-a-shared-instance-of-localdb) or a SQL Server Express Service install.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this really doesn't address my issues. Whether I use Windows Authentication or the 'murray' database user, I can log into the 'MSSQLLocalDB' instance just fine. There will never be multiple Windows Accounts accessing the database, so a shared LocalDB isn't really necessary. But I created a shared instance of 'MSSQLLocalDB' called 'MySharedDB' anyway. It showed up in the instance list as '.\MySharedDB' as expected. I was able to connect to it via Windows Authentication and the 'murray' database user. The .MDF was still not accessible while connected as 'murray' user.

Comment: Right.  With the automatic instance, it's Windows filesystem permissions you need to worry about, not SQL Server logins and permission.  If you want the database to be "owned" by SQL Server, not the user, you would move it to a shared instance or SQL Express Service install.

Comment: I did notice that 'Authenticated Users' and 'Users' didn't have the Full Control permission for the .MDF and .LDF files in the Windows file system. I granted the permissions, but didn't see any change in behavior. I can log into both the default and shared instances, but can't access the .MDF. I guess that leaves installing 'SQL Server Express Service'. I don't see that in VS's list of prerequisites; just 'SQL Server 201* Express LocalDB'. (I'm currently using 2016.) So, I'm assuming that's a manual installation? I'm not sure that's an option. Our Help Desk guys might murder me... :)